# Qual é a utilidade do hoisting no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, declaração-de-variável, hoisting

Antes do ES6, todas as variáveis de uma função são eram criadas independente de escopo do JS. Ou seja:

```
if(false) {
  var mensagem = "Olá!"; // declaração + atribuição
}
console.log(mensagem);
=> undefined
```

O retorno não é algo como um erro de referência, e sim `undefined`, o valor padrão de toda variável declarada no JavaScript.

Isso se dá por *hoisting*, mecanismo que declara todas as variáveis antes mesmo da linha de seu uso ser executada. O código acima é compilado para:

```
var mensagem;        // declaração
if(false) {
  mensagem = "Olá!"; // atribuição
}
console.log(mensagem);
=> undefined
```

Para mim, isso é na verdade um problema de performance e de encapsulamento de escopos. Estou certo? Existe alguma utilidade do hoisting no JavaScript? Por que esse comportamento era assim?

No ES6, com `let` e `const`, o hoisting no escopo de funções foi eliminado e o exemplo acima causa um `ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuidado, isso não é uma verdade. Nem todas as variáveis de uma função são criadas independente de escopo do JS. Veja:

```
function x() {
  y = 1;
  var z = 2;
}

x();

console.log(y); // logs "1" 
console.log(z); // Throws a ReferenceError: z is not defined outside x
```

Quando você declara uma variável sem o `var`, o compilador declara a variável global, e se tiver declarada com `var`, ela cria dentro do escopo.

Porém, no seu código, você declarou a variável com `var` e ele criou a variável no global-scope, porquê? Seu código funciona porque no javascript o `var` só existe em dois tipos de escopos: `global-scope` e `function-scope`, que são os escopos criados por funções. Os `block-scopes`, que são os criados por `{ ... }`, foram criados a partir do ES6 com a criação dos tipos `let` e `const`. Assim, como você está usando var, é como se todo o seu código estivesse no mesmo escopo, e por isso não dá erro. Agora, tente:

```
function teste() {
  var mensagem = "Olá!"; // declaração + atribuição
}
console.log(mensagem); // ReferenceError: mensagem is not defined
```

Então, na verdade, antes do ES6, quando só existia `var`, só se podia criar variáveis no `global scope` e no `function scope`. Javascript não tinha `block scopes`.

E no ES6 o hoisting não foi eliminado, mas sim criaram os `block scopes`, que são onde são criados as variáveis `let` e `const`. Por isso que se usar `let` ou `const` no seu exemplo dá erro:

```
if(false) {
  let mensagem = "Olá!"; // declaração + atribuição
}
console.log(mensagem); // ReferenceError: mensagem is not defined
```

---

O `hoisting` existe porque o interpretador `javascript` executa seu código em duas etapas: na primeira, *compiler-phase*, todas as variáveis e funções são alocadas na memória (é como se estivessemos passando as variáveis e funções pra cima), e na segunda, *execution-phase*, seu código começa a ser executado linha a linha.

O que nós, devs, podemos tirar disso é poder usar as variáveis e funções antes de serem declaradas:

```
i = 10;
var i;
```

e com métodos:

```
issoEhHoisting();
function issoEhHoisting(){
    console.log("aqui esta minha declaração");
}
```

Os dóis blocos acima somente funcionam por causa do `hoisting`.

Comment: Mas a pergunta é: qual a utilidade de existir o hoisting? Tem como falar disso na resposta? Você só falou de escopos.

Comment: realmente, editado!