# Como funciona o hoisting no ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Por exemplo, usando `var`, ao chamar a função abaixo desta forma:

```
function funcao(){
   console.log(foo);
   var foo = "mensagem";
}

funcao();
```

Irá retornar `undefined` por causa do *hoisting*, que move a variável `foo` para o topo da função sem valor definido.

E no caso do `let`, por exemplo:

```
function funcao(){
   console.log(foo);
   let foo = "mensagem";
}

funcao();
```

Irá retornar o erro `Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined`.

Sei que essas novas especificações do ES6 também sofrem *hoisting* (`let`, `const`, `class`...). Minha dúvida é qual seria a diferença entre uma coisa e outra, que tipo de *hoisting* (se é que pode-se dizer assim) que o `let` sofre se retorna erro, quando no caso do `var` não?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [var, const ou let? Qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206117/var-const-ou-let-qual-usar)

Comment: @MarceloBatista Qual a relação da pergunta com hoisting para ser duplicata?

Comment: Talvez [dessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278852/qual-é-a-utilidade-do-hoisting-no-javascript)

Comment: Tanto quanto sei não existe hoisting de `let` e `const`. Este argumento é indicado na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_Dead_Zone_and_errors_with_let) apesar de referir ES5 "... In ECMAScript 2015, let bindings are not subject to Variable Hoisting, which means that let declarations do not move to the top of the current execution contex..."

Comment: @Isac Pois é... tem lugares e pessoas que diz que sim... minha dúvida era saber a diferença entre hoisting antes do ES6 e após. Mas fecharam a pergunta relacionando a outra que nada tem a ver com a questão.

Comment: É interessante que apesar de a documentação referir o que eu disse, que não existe hoisting para `let`, existem posts no SOen a dizer precisamente o contrário.

Comment: @dvd é um mecanismo bem interessante o **Hoisting** porque graças a ele é possível usar uma variável ou função antes da declaração. Você quer entender como isso é feito internamente, sera isso?

Comment: @gato Antes do ES6 eu sei como funciona. Ainda não compreendi direito como funciona no ES6, com let.

Comment: Ontem gastei a manhã toda pesquisando isso e não cheguei a uma conclusão clara. Aí hoje venho aqui tentar uma ajuda e fecham a pergunta. Vai entender.

Comment: Será que sua dúvida é mesmo sobre hoisting, ou sobre escopo de função vs escopo de bloco?

Comment: @bfavaretto Cara, é sobre hoisting mesmo. Sobre escopo já está claro pra mim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O **Hoisting** é um comportamento do JavaScript de mover declarações para o topo do escopo, pode ser o escopo global ou de uma função.

No es6 há estas duas palavras chaves `let` e `const`. Vamos vê como o hoisting afeta esses dois novos recursos.

## Declaração com let

```
console.log(hoist);

let hoist = "A variável foi levada ao topo";
```

Saída:

> ReferenceError: hoist is not defined

Um erro de referência significa que a variável não foi para a memória do computador e ainda não existe, é diferente do que ocorre com o `var` que retornaria `undefined`.

Isso garante que nós sempre temos que declarar nossas variáveis primeiro.

Porém, uma implementação como esta resulta em `undefined` e temos que ficar mais atento:

```
let hoist;

console.log(hoist);

hoist = "A variavel foi levada ao topo";
```

Saída:

> undefined

Sendo assim, além de termos que *declarar a variável* antes de ser usada, nós também temos que *inicializa-la*.

## Declaração com const

```
console.log(hoist);

const hoist = "A variavel foi levada ao topo";
```

Saída:

> ReferenceError: hoist is not defined

Assim como o `let` o interpretador diz que a variável não existe lançando um `ReferenceError`. O mesmo irá ocorrer dentro de uma função.

Também devemos ficar atento numa declaração como esta:

```
const hoist;

console.log(hoist);

hoist = "A variavel foi levada ao topo";
```

Saída:

> SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

Isso nos mostra que uma constante deve ser *declarada* e *inicializada* antes de usar.

## Concluindo

O JavaScript leva ao topo as variáveis declaradas com `let` e `const` do es6, e a diferença é como elas são inicializadas.

Variáveis que são declaradas com  `let` ou `const` não são inicializadas no incio da execução, embora variáveis declaradas com `var` são inicializadas com o valor `undefined`.

Fontes:

[Hosting](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Hoisting)
[Understanding Hoisting in JavaScript](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

**Para começar, vale ressaltar alguns conceitos:**

A declaração de variáveis do tipo `var` pode ser um grande problema pelo simples fato dela poder se alterada independente de onde esteja, veja no exemplo, deixei alguns comentários com explicações:

```js
var a = 1; //aqui a variável é declarada e iniciada com o valor 1
console.log(a)

for(a; a<3; a++){ //aqui, é pego a mesma variável, e no loop, é somado o  valor 2, resultando em 3
  console.log(a)
}


function r () { 
  return   a+ 1; //aqui, a mesma variável, agora com o valor 3, irá ser somada com +1, resultando em 4 

}
console.log(r())
```

Havendo esse problema de declarações, o pessoal viu a necessidade da criação de variáveis que assumissem o seu valor aonde ela estivesse, esse é o caso do `let`. Com o  `let`, se declararmos ele dentro de uma `função`, o mesmo estará disponível apenas nela, sem a ocorrência do hosting para fora da mesma, exemplo:

```js
var r = 1;
function result () {
   let r = 1+1;
   return r;
}
console.log(r); //aqui irá exibir 1, pois estamos chamando a variável global

console.log(result()); //aqui é exibido o valor 2, pois foi chamado a função que contém a variável di tipo let
```

A variável `const` tem o mesmo comportamento da `let`, o que muda é que uma vez declarada, o seu valor não pode ser alterado, exemplo:

```js
const a = 1;

 a = a+2;
console.log(a)
```

Nesse exemplo, na saída será exibido o erro `"Assignment to constant variable"` que quer dizer que está sendo atribuído um valor à variável do tipo `const`, o que não é possível.

**CONCLUSÃO**

Graças ao hoisting, variáveis declaradas com a palavra-chave `var` podem ser utilizadas mesmo antes de sua declaração.

Por outro lado, as variáveis criadas com `let` só podem ser utilizadas após sua declaração, pois, apesar de serem elevadas, elas não são inicializadas.

Além das variáveis declaradas com `var` temos a possibilidade de usar constantes por meio da palavra-chave `const` ou utilizar variáveis com escopo de bloco através da `let`t .

Eu pessoalmente recomendo que você use sempre `const`, pois isso leva a menos erros. Ainda não vejo uma situação em que eu precise usar `var`.

Como regra geral, use `let` apenas para contadores de loop ou somente se você realmente precisar de reatribuição. Em qualquer outro lugar, use `const`.

Comment: Mas o `var` se declarado dentro de uma função, não será levado para fora também, será levado para o topo da função. No caso do `let` isso não acontece, mas afirmam que ele tb sofre hoisting. É isso que não entendi direito.

Comment: @dvd editei a conclusão, dê uma olhada.

Comment: @dvd a diferença, é que o `let` é uma variável com escopo de bloco, ou seja, só pode ser usada dentro do bloco,  se você der um `return variavelLet` dentro da função, ele retorna o valor assim que a função for chamada, mas se você der um `console.log(variavelLet)`,  será exibido o erro que a variável não foi definida.