# Hoisting ocorre com a variável dentro da função ou qualquer outro comando de bloco?

Tags: javascript

Declarações de variáveis com a palavra-chave `var` não possui diretamente um escopo local o seu escopo é dentro da função que a contém ou fora disso o escopo é global ([var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)).

Que nem no exemplo abaixo a variável `n1` será elevada para o topo do contexto de execução que é a função `test()` e nesse caso ela será visível por toda a função `test()`:

```js
function test() {
    if (10 == 10) {
        var n1 = 450;
    }
    
    console.log(n1); // 450
}

test();
```

Mas e se, por exemplo, em vez de eu utilizar a palavra-chave `var`, eu utilizar a palavra-chave `let` ou `const` nesse caso o escopo não vai mais ser a função `test()` e sim o comando `if` e a variável `n1` será visível apenas dentro do comando `if`, caso tente usá-la fora disso é retornado um erro:

```js
function test() {
    if (10 == 10) {
        let n1 = 450;
    }
    
    console.log(n1); // Será retornado erro.
}

test();
```

No caso do exemplo acima eu posso dizer que ocorreu **Hoisting** com a variável `n1`? isso porque ela foi movida para o contexto de execução que contém ela no caso não é mais a função `test()` e sim o comando `if`, isso pode ser considerado **Hoisting** ou não?

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu acabei de achar um artigo do MDN falando que hoisting de let é elevada para o bloco que a contém https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Block_scoping

Comment: Essa era a minha dúvida.

Comment: @bfavaretto talvez seja porque na época o ES6 ainda não estava implementado no navegador(?). Testando agora o mesmo código da minha pergunta o erro é outro: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'foo' before initialization`. Ou seja, ocorre o hoisting, porém a variável é inacessível antes da declaração.

Comment: O *Hoisting* com `var` é elevada para a função que contém ela. Já variáveis declarada com `let` ou `const` o *Hoisting* vai ser o bloco que foi definida ela. Pelo menos foi o que eu entendi :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Por outro lado, se o ES6 não estivesse disponível no navegador, daria erro no `let`. Aí eu não lembro mais. Pode ser que eu tenha informado o erro errado na pergunta, não me lembro. Acho isso o mais provável, porque em 2018 o Chrome já tinha suporte pro ES6.

Comment: Discutível se dá pra chamar de hoisting o reconhecimento da variável durante a "temporal dead zone", como dizem, somente pra lançar uma exceção. Na prática não há hoisting, não há como acessar a variável sem inicializar.

Comment: @ledevwd Esse conteúdo da MDN em pt_BR está errado!

Comment: @bfavaretto, mas *Hoisting* não é *Hoisting* quando a variável é elevada para o escopo que contém ela mesma e ser visível dentro desse escopo ou necessariamente deve ser possível acessar a variável antes mesmo dela ter sido declarada para ser considerado *Hoisting*?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como funciona o hoisting no ES6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/279182/como-funciona-o-hoisting-no-es6)

Comment: O @Sam já tinha citado o link dessa pergunta, eu dei uma lida e também nos links das perguntas citadas nos comentários, mas não ficou claro para mim.

Comment: @ledevwd "Hoisting" não é um termo tão preciso assim. Não vejo ser usado para descrever o comportamento do `let`, somente o do `var` (e parâmetros de funções e nomes de funções, ver detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/34728#34728)). E o fato é que nesses casos é possível acessar a variável antes do ponto onde ela é declarada. No caso do `let`, claramente o interpretador de JS precisa saber que ela existe para lançar a exceção, mas **eu** não chamaria de hoisting, porque não é a mesma coisa e pode confundir

Comment: @bfavaretto já havia reportado em feedback sobre o link para a Mozilla mas não surtiu efeito até hoje.

Comment: @EliseuB. diversos traduções no MDN estão desatualizadas ou simplesmente erradas, o mesmo ocorre com o site da microsoft MSDN, em C# a algum tempo o Bfavareto mesmo notou algo errado em minha resposta, quando conferi foi erro que eu copiei da documentação em portugues, em PHP também diversas páginas em portugues estão desatualizadas ou erradas, por tal motivo estou evitando ao máximo qualquer conteudo de doc em português, tanto em respostas quanto em comentários no site.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento e não tiro sua razão, você tem mais experiência e know-how e se tomou essa decisão é porque faz a diferença, eu notei algumas incongruências na documentação de CSS3 da W3C mas também  não obtive retorno, estou estudando PHP e fico com um pé atrás, aí consulto a documentação oficial, mas me perco bem por lá.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No caso do exemplo acima eu posso dizer que ocorreu Hoisting com a variável n1? isso porque ela foi movida para o contexto de execução que contém ela no caso não é mais a função test() e sim o comando if, isso pode ser considerado Hoisting ou não?

Não, a criação da variável não foi movida de lugar no seu exemplo. Ela foi declarada dentro do bloco do `if`, e é lá que ela existe, e só lá, e só a partir do momento em que estiver declarada. Ou seja, ela não está disponível para uso nem mesmo dentro do mesmo bloco, antes da linha onde é declarada. Por isso eu considero que não há hoisting. *Hoisting* é a expressão que se usa para descrever o comportamento oposto a esse, ou seja, o comportamento de escopo do `var`, argumentos de funções e funções nomeadas (mais detalhes [nesta minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-as-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-var-name-function-e-function-name#34728)).

Answer (score 4):

No primeiro exemplo, você está usando `var`, que é uma forma antiga de se declarar variáveis no JavaScript. Pode-se dizer que há *hoisting* em `var`, já que a declaração será elevada à função mais interna em que foi declarada, e não ao bloco.

Considere o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function outer() {
  function inner() {
    console.log(myVar); // undefined

    if (true) {
      var myVar = 500;
    }
    
    console.log(myVar); // 500
  }
  
  inner();
  // console.log(myVar); -> Isso lançaria um erro.
}

outer();
```

Pode-se dizer, então, que variáveis declaradas com `var` possuem a declaração acessível dentro da função mais interna em que foram declaradas. Portanto, variáveis `var` possuem escopo de **função** e não de bloco. Possuem, além disso, o chamado *hoisting*. Você pode saber mais sobre isso [nesta resposta do @bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-var-name-function-e-function-name#34728).

Vale notar, também, que a declaração foi movida para o começo de `inner`, e não para o começo de `outer`, já que a variável foi declarada dentro da função `inner`, e não `outer`. Nesse caso, `inner` é a função interna mais próxima.

---

Por outro lado, variáveis declaradas usando `let` ou `const` possuem o escopo de **bloco**. Não sei se posso, contudo, dizer que não possuem *hoisting*, já que até a especificação ECMAScript é um pouco vaga em relação a isso. Veja:

> `let` and `const` declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment. **The variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but *may* not be accessed in any way until the variable's LexicalBinding is evaluated**. A variable defined by a LexicalBinding with an Initializer is assigned the value of its Initializer's AssignmentExpression when the LexicalBinding is evaluated, not when the variable is created. If a LexicalBinding in a `let` declaration does not have an Initializer the variable is assigned the value undefined when the LexicalBinding is evaluated.
>
> <sup>Enfatizações próprias. [Fonte.](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations)</sup>

O trecho acima não diz, em nenhum momento, que `let` ou `const` não possuem *hoisting*, mas deixa claro que, conforme no trecho negritado, "as variáveis são criadas quando seus ambientes léxico são instanciados, mas não podem ser acessadas de nenhum modo até que o seu *LexicalBinding* seja avaliado". Isso significa que as variáveis que usaram essa declaração não poderão ser acessadas antes que o seu valor tenha sido avaliado.

Portanto, existe um "*temporal dead zone*" (veja [aqui](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_variables-assignment.html#const-and-let-temporal-dead-zone) ou [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443595/hoisting-ocorre-na-vari%C3%A1vel-dentro-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ou-qualquer-comando-de-bloco#comment853534_443595)). Ele impede que as variáveis declaradas com `let` ou `const` possam ser lidas até que o seu valor seja atribuído. Isso acontece porque se você tentar acessar uma variável `let` ou `const` antes que seu valor seja atribuído, você receberá um `ReferenceError`. Veja:

```js
console.log(x); // ReferenceError
let x = 10;
console.log(x);
```

Para saber mais, leia os links colocados durante esta resposta.

### Referência:

- Capítulo 10, [Variáveis e atribuição](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_variables-assignment.html), do livro JavaScript for impatient programmers.
- [10ª versão da especificação do ECMAScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html).

Comment: Ótima resposta!

Answer (score 3):

Eu diria que ocorreu hoisting no código com `var`, já que a variável foi "elevada" ao escopo da função.
Quando declaradas com `var`, as variáveis ou passam a ter escopo global ou o escopo da função que foram declaradas e é neste momento ocorre o **hoisting**.
já em declarações com `const` ou `let`, a variável se torna disponível apenas ao escopo em que ela foi declarada, seja uma função, uma estrutura de controle ou uma estrutura de repetição. É por isso que no código com `let` ocorre um erro.