# Explicação Hoisting JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Em JavaScript, toda variável que é declarada com a palavra-chave var é “elevada” (Hoisting) até o topo do contexto de execução, certo?

```js
function testandoMsg (){
 let b = 'B';
 console.log(a);
 console.log(b);
 var a = 'A';
}

testandoMsg();
```

Se o `var` é jogada pro topo da função por causa do Hoisting, por que dá undefined na execução?

Comment: [Como funciona o hoisting no ES6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279182/91) e [Qual é a utilidade do hoisting no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278852/91)

Comment: Obrigado, rray!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Em JavaScript, toda variável que é declarada com a palavra-chave var é
>   “elevada” (Hoisting) até o topo do contexto de execução, certo?

Você basicamente explicou sua pergunta com essa afirmação. Somente a declaração da váriavel sofre o Hoisting, não a atribuição de valores (isso acontece em run-time). Sendo assim, uma váriavel declarada sem valor é **undefined**.