# Por que não recebemos erro quando chamamos uma variável não declarada como propriedade de window?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, característica-linguagem

Temos, inicialmente, isso:

```js
var a = 0;
console.log(window.a === a); // true
```

Ok, então aqui comprovamos que, quando declaramos uma variável em escopo global, ela passa a ser uma propriedade do objeto `window`.

Agora, temos mais alguns cenários.

```js
var a = {};

console.log(a.foo); // a.foo não está declarado, entretanto recebemos 'undefined', ao invés do erro.
```

Agora me vem a questão. Por que, quando eu chamo por `a` sem que ele esteja declarado, recebo erro:

```js
console.log(a);
```

Mas quando chamo `window.a` recebo undefined:

```js
console.log(window.a)
```

Sendo que `window.a === a`.
Por que eu não recebo erro no ultimo snippet? O mesmo vale em por que não recebo erro quando chamo `var a = {}; console.log(a.foo)`, mas sim `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acessar `window.a` e `a` quando ambos não estão definidos geram resultados distintos porque são avaliados a partir de algoritmos distintos.

- `window.a` é avaliado buscando o valor da referência `a` na referência `window`;
- `a` é avaliado buscando o valor da referência de `a`;

## Referência

Primeiro, precisamos entender como o JavaScript referencia cada objeto, que se dá através de uma interface denominada [`Reference`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-reference-specification-type). Um objeto `Reference` é composto de três partes:

- O valor base;
- O nome da referência;
- Uma flag booleana que define se é estrito (*strict*);

O valor base de uma referência pode ser `undefined`, um objeto, um booleano, uma string, um símbolo, um número ou um [registro de ambiente](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-environment-records). Quando o valor base é `undefined` significa que o objeto `Reference` não pode ser resolvido.

Com isso em mente, precisamos definir alguns procedimentos que serão necessários para entender o algoritmo mais adiante.

- [`GetBase(V)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getbase), retorna o valor base da referência `V`;
- [`GetReferencedName(V)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getreferencedname), retorna o nome da referência `V`;
- [`IsStrictReference(V)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isstrictreference), retorna se a referência `V` é estrita ou não;
- [`HasPrimitiveBase(V)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-hasprimitivebase), retorna se o valor base da referência `V` é primitivo (booleano, string, símbolo ou número);
- [`IsPropertyReference(V)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ispropertyreference), retorna se o valor base da referência `V` é um objeto ou é primitivo;
- [`IsUnresolvableReference(V)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isunresolvablereference), retorna se o valor base da referência `V` é `undefined`;

## Acessando o objeto `a`

Assim, quando o código será analisado identifica-se o objeto `a` internamente é definida uma referência (`Reference`) para ele e como é um objeto que não poderá ser resolvido, o valor `base` ficará como `undefined`. Ao executar um código que demande do valor de `a`, tal como `console.log(a)`, será executado o método [`GetValue(V)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getvalue) da referência seguindo o algoritmo:

1. `ReturnIfAbrupt(V)`.
2. If `Type(V)` is not `Reference`, return `V`.
3. Let `base` be `GetBase(V)`.
4. If `IsUnresolvableReference(V)` is true, throw a `ReferenceError` exception.
5. If `IsPropertyReference(V)` is true, then

   1. If `HasPrimitiveBase(V)` is true, then

      1. Assert: In this case, base will never be `undefined` or `null`.
      2. Set base to `!ToObject(base)`.
   2. Return `?base.[[Get]](GetReferencedName(V), GetThisValue(V))`.
6. Else,

   1. Assert: `base` is an `Environment Record`.
   2. Return `?base.GetBindingValue(GetReferencedName(V), IsStrictReference(V))`.

Neste caso temos uma referência com valor base `undefined` para o objeto `a`, então no passo 4, quando feita a validação `IsUnresolvableReference(V)` é retornado `true` e, portanto, lançado a exceção `ReferenceError`.

## Acessando o objeto `window.a`

De forma semelhante a quando é acessado diretamente o objeto `a`, para que seja possível avaliar o valor de `window.a` também serão definidas referências internamente, uma para o objeto `window` e outra para o objeto `a`. Para o objeto `a` será uma referência igual a anterior, com valor base `undefined`, mas a diferença está na existência da referência ao objeto `window` que existe e pode ser resolvido. Assim, diferente da situação anterior, em que o valor de `a` é avaliado a partir de `GetValue(V)`, o valor de `window.a` será avaliado a partir da função `[[Get]](P, Receiver)` da interface [`Object`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-type), sendo `P` a referência para o objeto `a` e `Receiver` a referência ao objeto `window`. O algoritmo executado para tal será:

1. If `P` was previously observed as a non-configurable, non-writable own data property of the target with value `V`, then `[[Get]]` must return the `SameValue` as `V`.
2. If `P` was previously observed as a non-configurable own accessor property of the target whose `[[Get]]` attribute is `undefined`, the `[[Get]]` operation must return `undefined`.

Como o valor `P` será a referência ao objeto `a`, cujo valor base é `undefined`, será executado o passo 2, fazendo com que `[[Get]]` retorne `undefined`.

## Fazer `window.a` é igual a `a`?

Não, como mostrado, os valores serão avaliados de forma diferente e produzirá resultados diferentes.

## Mas por que então `window.a === a` é verdadeiro?

Porque quando a variável é definida uma referência a ela é armazenada dentro do objeto "global" do escopo atual. Quando é definida no escopo global da aplicação, esse objeto será o `window`. Quando é definida em um escopo limitado, esse objeto será outro (e não sei se é acessível em tempo de execução tal como é o `window`).

Para confirmar essa informação basta verificar o algoritmo utilizado ao definir uma variável, executando [`PutValue(V, W)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-putvalue):

1. `ReturnIfAbrupt(V)`.
2. `ReturnIfAbrupt(W)`.
3. If `Type(V)` is not `Reference`, throw a `ReferenceError` exception.
4. Let `base` be `GetBase(V)`.
5. If `IsUnresolvableReference(V)` is true, then

   1. If `IsStrictReference(V)` is true, then

      1. Throw a `ReferenceError` exception.
   2. Let `globalObj` be `GetGlobalObject()`.
   3. Return `?Set(globalObj, GetReferencedName(V), W, false)`.
6. Else if `IsPropertyReference(V)` is true, then

   1. If `HasPrimitiveBase(V)` is true, then

      1. Assert: In this case, base will never be `undefined` or `null`.
      2. Set base to `!ToObject(base)`.
   2. Let `succeeded` be `?base.[[Set]](GetReferencedName(V), W, GetThisValue(V))`.
   3. If `succeeded` is false and `IsStrictReference(V)` is true, throw a `TypeError` exception.
   4. Return.
7. Else,

   1. Assert: `base` is an `Environment Record`.
   2. Return `?base.SetMutableBinding(GetReferencedName(V), W, IsStrictReference(V))`.

Que basicamente, quando é feito `var a = 1`, novamente será definida uma referência ao objeto `a`, inicialmente com valor base `undefined` devido ao Hoisting.

- [Qual é a utilidade do hoisting no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278852/5878)
- [Como funciona o hoisting no ES6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279182/5878)

Assim, executando o algoritmo, no passo 5 `IsUnresolvableReference(V)` retornará verdadeiro e, assim, não sendo uma referência estrita, buscará a referência ao objeto global `GetGlobalObject()`, que neste caso, por se tratar de uma variável global será o objeto `window`, e será definido o campo `GetReferencedName(V)` com o valor `W`. Por isso, ao ser feito `var a` teremos também o valor em `window.a` (ou `window['a']`).

A partir disso a referência de `a` poderá ser resolvida e nas próximas vezes que houver uma atribuição ao objeto `a` no código o passo 6 será executado, atualizando o valor do mesmo.

## Então `var a = 1` é o mesmo que fazer `window["a"] = 1`?

Não, embora produza o mesmo resultado. Como vimos, ao avaliar a expressão `var a = 1` será executado a operação `Set(window, "a", 1, false)`, porém o valor `"a"` que será a chave no objeto `window` é avaliado a partir da referência ao objeto `a`, através da função `GetReferencedName(V)`, enquanto fazer `window["a"] = 1` não é gerado esta referência interna.

Comment: Excelente resposta, Obrigado.

Answer (score 8):

Sabemos que quando tentamos ler uma variável que não está disponível no escopo atual o erro (`ReferenceError`) é lançado. Para saber mais, leia [este documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/N%C3%A3o_definido).

Também sabemos que quando uma variável é declarada no "escopo global" utilizando `var`, ela se torna também disponível no **objeto** `window` (ou `global`, se estiver utilizando Node.js). Desse modo, uma variável estar-se-á disponível no objeto `window` somente se estiver sido declarada no escopo global usando `var` (ou nenhum tipo de declaração).

Veja no *snippet* escondido abaixo esse comportamento:

```js
window.a = 'a'; // Estará disponível em `window` (definido explicitamente).
console.log('a ->', window.a);

b = 'b'; // Estará disponível em `window`.
console.log('b ->', window.b);

var c = 'c'; // Estará disponível em `window`.
console.log('c ->', window.c);

(() => {
  var d = 'd'; // Não estará disponível em `window`, já que está em um outro escopo.
})();
console.log('d ->', window.d);

let e = 'e'; // Não estará disponível em `window`, já que usa `let`.
console.log('e ->', window.e);

let f = 'f'; // Não estará disponível em `window`, já que usa `let`.
console.log('f ->', window.f);
```

<sub>Não posso negar, esse tipo de comportamento é estranho e corrobora com a imensa quantidade de críticas ao JavaScript.</sub>

---

Além desses dois conceitos, para entendermos a diferença dessa questão, devemos ter o conhecimento do seguinte comportamento dos objetos:

> Propriedades não definidas de um objeto são `undefined`. <sub>[[Fonte]](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos)</sub>

Isso significa que se você tentar acessar um valor de um objeto que não foi definido, ele retornará `undefined`:

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(obj.iAmNotDefined); // undefined
```

Esse comportamento, documentado na [especificação da linguagem](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262), justifica o fato de nenhum erro ser lançado ao tentar acessar uma propriedade que não existe em um objeto. E aí está a resposta para a sua pergunta! Tendo em vista que **`window` é um objeto**, ao tentar acessar uma "variável global" (isto é, uma propriedade) que não está definida, o valor `undefined` será retornado e nenhum erro será disparado.

Para concluir, vamos colocar em comparação as duas abordagens...

A **leitura de uma variável** não definida causa um erro:

```js
console.log(a); // Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

O **acesso de uma propriedade** não definida retorna `undefined` (não lança nenhum erro, porque não está errado):

```js
console.log(window.a); // undefined
```

---

Frisando novamente, é importante ter em mente que mesmo se tratando de um **mesmo valor**, o **erro se dá na forma de recuperá-lo**. A especificação estipula que ler uma variável não definida deve lançar um erro, mas acessar uma propriedade indefinida de um objeto (como `window`) não deve lançar erros (veja a comparação que fiz acima).

Pense na diferença entre "leitura" (a leitura da variável) e "acesso" (o acesso de um valor em um objeto).

Comment: "A leitura de uma variável não definida causa um erro:" 
Ok, mas a questão é: toda variável é uma propriedade do objeto window, então na verdade chamar por ela é chamar pela propriedade de window, não?

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo sim, é o que está na minha resposta.

Comment: Nem toda variável é uma propriedade do objeto `window`. Irei editar a resposta frisando isso.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript é uma linguagem cheia de esquisitices porque foi definida de forma muito rápida. A principal decisão ruim  foi ter [tipagem fraca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101), e pior, adotaram critérios bem ruins para transformar um tipo em outro implicitamente. Pode-se argumentar que isso facilita para o programador novato, mas é um tiro no pé de marketing porque depois as pessoas terão que lidar com o custo disto pro resto da vida (pra falar a verdade eu acho que nem acreditavam que isso ia dar certo). Então espero tudo confuso em vez de um erro claro onde pode dar confusão. JS opta por tentar fazer funcionar mesmo que não dê certo.

Então o `===` etá comparando propriedades do objeto `window`, mesmo que um dos lados não tenha ele escrito explicitamente, como a própria pergunta indica, uma variável global entra como propriedade do objeto `window`.

Essa falta de critérios fez ser inconsistente, provavelmente foi acaso ser assim, não perceberam que isto aconteceria.

Lembrando que objetos em JS na verdade são tabelas *hash*, portanto os que parecem variáveis de um objeto na verdade são chaves dentro dessa tabela e se a chave não existe ele não pode dizer que a variável não existe, porque no fundo o que você fez é uma busca por um dado dentro  dessa tabela e não encontrou nada, é um erro de dado e não de sintaxe ou semântica, a linguagem não sabe de nada disso. Poderia ser tratado de forma diferente? Poderia, mas perderia alguma flexibilidade, e provavelmente alguém se arrependeu e queria mudar, mas já era tarde demais. É algo bonitinho, mas traz problemas.

O objeto `window` tem elementos porque ele é uma tabela *hash*, você tenta acessar e recebe que o dado é indefinido (é um valor indefinido, mas é um valor).

Uma variável real a linguagem pode determinar que há erro ela é um elemento sintático do código não é só um dado contido em uma coleção que se passa por um objeto estruturado. Resolveram neste caso não considerar que ela também é uma propriedade de `window`, apesar de ser porque a sintaxe não indica isso. Dado que a linguagem escolheu o caminho de colocar uma variável global como parte do objeto `window` e que não ter um nome dessa variável dar um valor indefinido, o esquisito é esse comportamento.

Isso pode ser melhor percebido em [Os objetos nativos do JS são arrays associativos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/101).

Então quando declara a variável global `a` na verdade é o mesmo que fazer

```
window["a"] = 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/Window.js).

Obviamente as variáveis locais não acontece isto.

Então a pergunta mais correta seria:

> Por que dá erro quando tenta acessar uma variável global não definida, já que ela faz parte do objeto `window`, ainda que implicitamente, e que propriedades não existentes de um objeto resultam em `undefined`?

Só os criadores da linguagem podem responder isso.

O motivo exato porque escolheram fazer isso só quem escolheu e pode dizer  e pode ser até o famoso "queria assim", então especula-se que a motivação possa ser a que citei.  Pode-se argumentar que a especificação da linguagem determinou assim e ela pode determinar o que quiser, não importa se é coerente e faça sentido.

JavaScript provavelmente é a linguagem que mais vale o "o que importa é funcionar, não estar certo" que agrada amadores e iniciantes que verão resultado mesmo que isso traga problemas, o pior é a inconsistência, você tem que saber as regras em cada contexto para não ter surpresas, ou seja, a linguagem que é fácil de aprender é difícil de usar.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]