# Variavel de escopo global e local

Tags: javascript, variáveis, declaração-de-variável, escopo-de-variáveis

Se eu imprimir a variável de escopo global dentro de um escopo local, não é permitido que eu à redeclare novamente no escopo local. Por que? Por exemplo, se eu fizer:

```js
let a = 2; {
  let a = 3;
  console.log(a) //aqui aparece 3
}
console.log(a) //aqui aparece 2
```

Ate aí tudo bem. Mas se eu fizer:

```js
let a = 2; {
  console.log(a) //aqui aparece 2
  let a = 3; //aqui ja da erro, não aceita
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode declarar novamente, esse não é o problema do código que você postou.

```js
let a = 2;
{
    console.log(a); //aqui aparece 2
    let a = 3; // aqui ja da erro, não aceita
}
```

Você escreveu `aqui aparece 2`, mas não é isso o que está acontecendo. O problema está no próprio `console.log(a)`, não no `let a = 3`.

O que está acontecendo aqui se chama `hoisting`. O JavaScript reserva todas as variáveis declaradas no escopo local logo ao iniciar o escopo, mas apesar desse `let a` já estar reservado, você não pode acessa-lo até depois da linha que ele foi declarado.

Ou seja, o `console.log(a)` está tentando acessar o `let a` local, mas o `let a` local ainda não é válido, e esse é a fonte do erro.

Repare também que esse é o comportamento apenas de variáveis declaradas como `let` ou `const`. Variáveis declaradas como `var` podem ser acessadas antes de sua declaração sem lançar exceções, porem seu valor será `undefined`.

Comment: Ótima resposta, bem observado que **ali** não aparece 2.

Answer (score 9):

Não aconselho fazer isso, mas com `var` você pode fazê-lo. O `let` realmente trabalha com a declaração na ordem correta, inclusive foi o motivo dele ter sido criado. O errado era o `var`, e se você deseja fazer algo desta forma, você deveria justificar o motivo.

Nenhum *designer* de linguagem precisa justificar algo que a linguagem não faz. Eles precisaram sim justificar porque o `var` consegue ter duas variáveis com mesmo nome no mesmo escopo, o que não faz sentido e gera confusão. Como eles não conseguiram justificar e foi considerado erro, criaram uma forma que não fazia isso.

Com o uso do `var` o primeiro `console.log()` está acessando a variável `a` de escopo mais global e o segundo está acessado outra variável de escopo mais local, mas as pessoas vão achar que é a mesma variável porque tem o mesmo nome. Acho que seria interessante entender o que é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

O `var` faz algo chamado [*hoisting*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278852/101), o `let` não faz, nunca, então no código não é isto que acontece, tanto que dá erro se tentar a mesma coisa que causaria o *hoisting*. Veja [Qual é a diferença entre declaração de variáveis usando "let" e "var"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101) e [Melhores práticas na declaração de variáveis em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171327/101).

```js
var a = 2;
{
    console.log(a)
    var a = 3;
    console.log(a)
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Hoisting.js).

Answer (score 3):

Seu código não está funcionando porque você não mudou de escopo. Envolver o código com {} não significa que o mesmo está em um escopo diferente. Para mudar de escopo você deve criar uma função. Segue o exemplo:

```js
let a = 1;

function test() {
  let a = 2;
  console.log(a);
}

console.log(a);

test();
```

> Não é porque o código acima funciona que seja a melhor opção. Não é recomendável utilizar dois nomes iguais em seu código. Se ambos os nomes são iguais, significa que ambos tem o mesmo valor e tipo de dados, logo não precisam ser declarados duas vezes, apenas receber uma nova atribuição quando necessário.

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas discordo de que "{ }" não signifique está em um escopo diferente. Eu coloquei as { } e no primeiro exemplo que eu dei, ficou em escopo diferente sim. Esse código aí que vc colocou, é o mesmo que eu escrevi no primeiro exemplo. Pode ver que, dentro dessa função test, se vc colocar o log antes de declarar o a, vai da erro do mesmo jeito.