# Diferença entre escopo global e local

Tags: terminologia, escopo-de-variáveis, scope

Recentemente me deparei com o conceito de escopo global e local e, estou tendo grandes dificuldade em entende-los em termos de conceituação. O que seria escopo em sua definição, e escopo global e local?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta não fala de linguagens específicas então cuidado porque essa definição exata pode variar um pouco de linguagem para linguagem. O geral é igual, mas os detalhes mudam.

Já falei sobre escopo em [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

## Global

Escopo global vale por toda sua aplicação, qualquer parte dela em execução tem acesso às variáveis de escopo global.

[Elas costumam ser perigosas e devem ser evitadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101). Não é que não possa fazer, mas você precisa entender o que está fazendo, saber que ela pode confundir com outras coisas, ela está circulando por aí e visível em qualquer lugar. Além de conflitos de nomes pode ter problemas de concorrência quando a aplicação permite isso.

O [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) costuma ser global também.

## Local

Escopo local significa que a variável tem abrangência limitada. O mais comum é ser  função, então ela só é visível dentro daquela função e não se confunde com outras partes do código.

Acho que deve imaginar que essa variável é mais fácil de gerenciar por isso, você sabe onde olhar para entender onde ela pode ser modificada, não tem o risco da alteração vir de todos os locais.

Se você acessar uma variável global localmente ela pode se confundir com uma local. O compilador tem algum critério para definir se está acessando a local ou a global de mesmo nome. Em geral tem algum mecanismo para resolver a ambiguidade, mas nem sempre. É mais comum ter uma forma de eliminar a ambiguidade de variável regional.

Além do conflito de nomes ela restringe o tempo de vida da variável e isso é bom.

Parâmetros são variáveis de escopo local (já vi linguagem que isso não era verdade, mas é raro).

## Regional

Variáveis de uma classe ou estrutura podem ser consideradas locais porque o escopo é limitado, mas nem tanto quanto acontece na função, então alguns preferem dizer que o escopo é regional, a variável pode ser acessada por todos os métodos daquele tipo ou eventualmente até fora dele desde que indique que é a variável deste tipo ou objeto.

## Bloco

[O escopo pode ser ser menor que o local](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/413195/101). A maioria das linguagens tem escopo do bloco de comandos, então uma variável pode ter vida só dentro do bloco e não por toda a função. Algumas linguagens fazem isso de forma confusa. JavaScript é uma delas, [o escopo só fica certo quando usa o `let`, com o `var` isso não acontece](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente é uma parte, por exemplo no código abaixo, declarei na primeira linha "var x = 1;" no escopo global, ou seja o escopo dela é a parte completa do código, ela é visível por todo o código, enquanto que "x" dentro da função "escopo" só faz parte do escopo da função "escopo" somente.

Para exemplificar criei duas funções e cada função tem o seu escopo, na primeira função eu crio uma variável "x" só que no escopo local da função, ou seja, só na função que existe aquele x, então quando chamo a função escopo e mostro o "x" ele mostra o valor do escopo global, agora criei uma outra função que tem o seu próprio escopo, só que não criei uma nova variável usei o "x" do escopo global e alterei o seu valor agora quando mostro o valor você percebe que foi alterado já que alterei do escopo global e não do local.

```js
var x = 1; // Variável no escopo global
function escopo(){
  console.log("Chamou escopo");
  var x = 2; // Variável no escopo local
}
function escopo2(){
  console.log("Chamou escopo2");
  x = 2; // Variável no escopo global
}
escopo();
console.log(x);
escopo2();
console.log(x);
```

Sabendo que a função tem o seu próprio escopo é possível criar funções sem se preocupar se existe uma variável no escopo global com o mesmo nome por exemplo, assim você tem uma liberdade maior naquele escopo para trabalhar.