# Como alterar valor de uma variável com uma função?

Tags: javascript, funções, variáveis

```js
var x = 2

function alterar(x) {
  return x += 2
}

alterar(x)

console.log(x)


console.log(alterar(x))
```

Por que a variável `x` não altera o valor? Ela só altera quando eu chamo a função, mas depois volta ao valor inicial. Tem alguma forma de alterar uma variável através de uma função?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Em geral não faz muito sentido fazer isso, mas se quiser mesmo fazer a forma de fazer é passar o valor por referência. Tem mais detalhes sobre o assunto em [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

Acontece que JS não tem uma forma de passar valores por referência de forma natural. Existem alguns tipos de dados que já são passados por referência, alguns [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), que não nos ajuda porque queremos justamente mudar o valor e alguns mutáveis, que nos atende.

Então o que fazemos é encapsular um valor em um tipo desses para que o valor seja alterado dentro da função e reflita onde a variável foi criada. Não é bonito mas é a única forma de fazer isto em JS, até por ter pouca necessidade.

Podemos usar um objeto ou um *array* para isso já que eles são tipos por referência mutáveis. Farei com *array*:

```js
function alterar(x) {
    return x[0] += 2;
}
var x = [2];
alterar(x);
console.log(x);
console.log(x[0]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ChangeVariable3.js).

Quase sempre isso deve ser feito por questões de eficiência, que não é um objetivo de JavaScript, por isso não deveria se preocupar em fazer isto se não é algo natural, o retorno dá o resultado que espera, você já tinha feito o que precisa, não há necessidade de mudar o valor da variável assim, só faltou guardar o valor na própria variável:

```js
function alterar(x) {
    return x += 2;
}
var x = 2;
x = alterar(x);
console.log(x);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ChangeVariable2.js).

Coloquei `;` porque o não uso dele é uma mania ruim que pegou agora, tem gente que gosta de ensinar como fazer coisas que vão trazer problemas, provavelmente para sacanear as pessoas desavisadas.

Não altere diretamente variáveis externas, conforme foi falado, funciona, mas não é o certo, é como o `;` funciona, mas dará problema em algum momento.

A forma realizada não é ideal porque ela está mudando o valor de `x` local e depois retornando esse valor, e esse caso não tem porque mudar o valor local de `x`, basta fazer a conta e retornar (em outro caso pode ser que fizesse sentido mudar o `x`.

Note que o `x` local não é o mesmo `x` global=, pesar das variáveis terem o mesmo nome não é a mesma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Veja mais sobre [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) e [Diferença entre escopo global e local](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/450218/101). Quando você não coloca um parâmetro, o `x` é considerado global, aí só existe ela, e cria confusão, por isso não faça.

Se tiver controle sobre a versão que está usando seria até melhor usar [`let`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101) do que `var` que não permite o global se confundir com o local. Melhor ainda se usar TypeScript. O `let` não funciona em versões antigas (o que é verdade em alguns raros navegadores por aí). Programar em Node/[Deno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/444449/101) é diferente de fazer JS em um *browser*.

Eu quis mostrar sem mudar o conteúdo da sua função, mas é melhor até fazer o seguinte:

```js
function alterar(x) {
    return x + 2;
}
var x = 2;
x = alterar(x);
console.log(x);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ChangeVariable.js).

Answer (score 1):

A variável não vai alterar o valor desta forma porque quando vc passa como argumento, o javascript está passando uma cópia do valor da variável e não o ponteiro de memória da variável em si.

Para alterar essa variável externa ao bloco, basta alterar ela diretamente sem passar como argumento. O return também não é necessário.

```
var x = 2

function alterar() {  
  x += 2  
}  

alterar()  
console.log(x)  
alterar()  
console.log(x)
```

Agora, se vc ainda quer alterar passando como argumento, vc pode criar um objeto e guardar o valor dentro dela. E o return ainda funcionaria.

```
var objeto = {x: 2}

function alterar(obj) {
    return obj.x += 2
}

console.log(alterar(objeto))
console.log(alterar(objeto))
```

Comment: Obrigado! Esclareceu bastante minhas dúvidas, mas quando eu devo passar parâmetros pra uma função?

Comment: Imagina. Para essa outra pergunta, acho que a discussão aqui ficaria um pouco extensa. Entraria mais em questões de boas práticas e organização de código. Pelo pouco que pesquisei sobre, declarar variáveis no javascript como "var" também já não é mais recomendado hoje em dia, recomenda-se declarar como const ou let. Recomendo dar uma pesquisada sobre boas práticas de javascript para entender melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Vc está retornando o valor e passando a variável como argumento. Pra ter o efeito que vc quer teria que ser algo como:

var x = 2

function alterar() {
x += 2;
return x
}

alterar()

console.log(x)

console.log(alterar())

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado pela velocidade da resposta, me ajudou muito! Eu pensava que seu não passasse o parametro para a função, o programa ia dar como não definida

Comment: Se a variável existir no escopo global vai funcionar. Não é das melhores praticas pra aplicações mais avançadas mas funciona.